# Abnormal file writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

**My Question:**

I made a password generator app on Tkinter. The passwords entered by the user can be saved as HTML files. But I have a problem encounter which is "TextIOWrapper.write () takes exactly one argument (0 given)". It runs fine but when I enter the password length and number of passwords it is not written in the HTML file. But the User ID is written.

**My Code:**

```
with open('password.html', 'w') as file:
   if file:
      messagebox.showinfo(title = "Wisteria 1.0.0", message = "Password generated successfully. To see you your password locate to password.html")
                    
      file.write("<h1 style = 'color: blue;'>Wisteria Information</h1>" + "<br>")
                    
      file.write("User ID : ")
                    
      for uid_number in range(1):
         for uid_generate in range(10):
            randomize_uid = random.choice(user_id)
            file.write(randomize_uid)
         file.write()
                    
       file.write('<br>')
                    
       file.write("Password Length : ")
       file.write(str(password_length))
       file.write('<br>')
                    
       file.write("Number of passwords : ")
       file.write(str(number_of_passwords))
       file.write('<br>')
                    
       file.write("Here is your password. You can choose in the following:" + '<br><br>')
                    
       for num_pass in range(number_of_passwords):
          for pass_len in range(password_length):
             randomize_characters = random.choice(characters)
             file.write(randomize_characters)
          file.write()
                    
       file.write('<br>')
                    
       now = datetime.now()
       date_time_string = now.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y - %I:%M:%S %p")
                    
       file.write("Date Generated : " , date_time_string)
                    
       file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an argument to `file.write`.

The program below reproduces your problem:

```py
with open("./file1.txt", "w")as f:
    f.write()
```

Output:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx", line 2, in <module>
    f.write()
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

`file.write()` is pointless. If you really want to keep it, you can write an empty string, like this `file.write("")`.